# Error while uploading file larger than 15MB to Google Drive using a html form “cannot read property 'fileName of undefined'”

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm a real beginner. I cannot upload files larger than 15 MB on my drive. How can I find the problem? everything is fine under 15 mb, but beyond that I have this message:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getUrl" of undefined.at uploadFiles (server: 31)

Here's what I've made so far:

### Server.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
        
}

function uploadFiles(form) {
  try {
    
    var dropbox = "_Upload FreeMaster"; // Input the name of the folder to be used for holding the uploaded files
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);
    
        
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox); // Otherwise by default a 'dropbox' folder will be created
    }
    
    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);
    return "File uploaded successfully. Thank you " + form.myName + file.getUrl();
  }
    
  catch (error) {
    return error.toString();
  }  
    
  finally {MailApp.sendEmail ("OOOOO@gmail.com", // to field for the email. Can input multiple, ie: "1@email.com, 2@email.com",
                  "000000@gmail.com",       // from field
                  "Master upload detected",      // email subject
                  "You have a new file upload to review by"  + file.getUrl("here"+ form.myName) );  // email body+ form.myName
           
           MailApp.sendEmail (form.Email, // to field for the email. Can input multiple, ie: "1@email.com, 2@email.com",
                  "00000@gmail.com",       // from field
                  "Free Master upload detected",      // email subject
                  "Hi, Your Upload has been received. We'll get back to you ASAP. Best  "  );  // email body
          
           
    }
  
}
```

---

### Form.html

```
<!doctype html>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<div align="center">
  <p><img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/pKoQXuy0rTsExANby80kcRgKU4CWZwR7hiqQlIGb-Sw4tcBlnAKAU9k1fRQz6DPzpi-zUb7wEnRZndvBAldGxzo7ikIsJMK235Kuwi5ZPcm2UVnNn_21heMR3uoy=w867"></p>
  <table width="459" border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="862"><div align="center">
          <hr>
        </div>
          <form id="myForm" align="center">
            <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Your name..">
            <input type="mail" name="Email" placeholder="Your email..">
            <input type="file" name="myFile">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload File" 
           onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                    .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                    return false;">
          </form>
          <div id="output"></div>
          <script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
        document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }
          </script>
        <style>
 input { display:block; margin: 30px; }
 
          </style>
        <hr></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I had no issue with the server side code you shared.  For debugging further, try inspecting (console.log for instance) the value of  `form.myFile` before you try to use it.  I would also suggest revising your Form.html file to follow the guidelines here (maybe you aren't sending a good "form" object): https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#index.html_4

Comment: Perhaps you have set the file size limit incorrectly in your form.